# Can we write GraphQL query for getting data based on predicate(condition)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa, graphql

I need to write graphql query with some predicate like

```
Select * from User Where loginId like "abc%"
```

In GraphQL :

```
{
  getWithPredicate(clazz : String, predicates : Predicates){
        loginId
        enabled
        accountLocked
        accountExpired
        accountExpireBy
        createdBy
  }

}
```

Please suggest, if any default implementation is available in graphql.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. I once wrote a query like this. I needed to search the database using some search terms.

```
query ($title: String!, $company: String!, $city: String!, $investor: String!) {
    jobs(
      where: {
        and: [
          { title: { ilike: $title } },
          { company: { name: { ilike: $company } } },
          { city: { ilike: $city } },
          {company: {company_investors:{investor:{name: {ilike: $investor}}}}}
          
        ]
      }
    ) {
      id
      title
      city
      company {
        name
        id
        company_investors {
          investor {
            name
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This query should be in .graphqls file, right?

Comment: @JyotiKolape yes. you can store it in a variable. 
`const MY_QUERY = <query here>`

Answer (score 0):

```
# glob: I want all the titles that contain the word 'History'.
# The wildcard * stands for any non-empty string.

  example_glob: allMarkdownRemark(
    filter: { frontmatter: { title: { glob: "*History*" } } }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Complete list of possible operators**

- `eq:` short for **equal**, must match the given data exactly
- `ne:` short for **not equal**, must be different from the given data
- `regex:` short for **regular expression**, must match the given pattern
- `glob:` short for **global**, allows to use wildcard * which acts as a
  placeholder for any non-empty string
- `in:` short for **in array**, must be an element of the array
- `nin:` short for **not in array**, must NOT be an element of the array
- `gt:` short for **greater than**, must be greater than given value
- `gte:` short for **greater than or equal**, must be greater than or equal
  to given value
- `lt:` short for **less than**, must be less than given value
- `lte:` short for **less than or equal**, must be less than or equal to
  given value
- `elemMatch:` short for **element match**, this indicates that the field you
  are filtering will return an array of elements, on which you can
  apply a filter using the previous operators